# The values of the iteration $z^2 + c$ for c inside the Mandelbrot set

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-dynamics

I'm wondering for which $c \in M$ (where M is the Mandelbrot set) the sequence
$((z \to z^2 + c)^k(0))_k$ has a subsequence converging to $0$. One trivial solution is $c = 0$, though I cannot find any other. This makes me wonder if $c=0$ is the only solution. Thanks for any kind of advice.

Comment: There's $c = -1$.

Comment: There is exactly one such value of $c$ near the center of each [periodic bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Main_cardioid_and_period_bulbs). More generally, these values of $c$ are associated with the [hyperbolic components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Hyperbolic_components). You can find such $c$ values by solving equations of the form $f_c^k(0)=0$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thanks, this was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: in dynamical terms, you are asking when the critical point $z=0$ has a recurrent orbit. outside of the case where the orbit is periodic (as mentionned by Mark), there are many (uncountably many) values of $c$ in the boundary of $M$ for which this is true.